# Load ready project - Eclipse Java EE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I need this application

https://developers.redhat.com/ticket-monster/

Here is tutorial but I do not have time to rewrite it

I found ready project on GitHub but i dont know how i can import this on my Eclipse.

https://github.com/jboss-developer/ticket-monster/releases/tag/2.7.0.Final-with-tutorials

I have the newest version Eclipse and installed JBoss Tools 4.9.0.Final.

Please help me! I'm green in it

Comment: zip folder already has a README.html ../ticket-monster-2.7.0.Final-with-tutorials/cordova/README.html and has a section for how to import it. Have you tried that  ? Also do you want only demo project to be imported ?

Comment: @Ros5292 i saw that but i need open this. Yes i want only demo project in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps. I was able to import your maven project in eclipse

```
1. Open eclipse
2. Click File > Import
3. Type Maven in the search box under Select an import source:
4. Select Existing Maven Projects
5. Click Next
6. Click Browse and select the folder that is the root of the Maven project (probably contains the pom.xml file) **In your case demo project.**
7. Click Next
8. Click Finish
```

Let me know if you need any help, can provide you with screen shots if needed.

Comment: Thanks bro, its work. I have one more anwser. I runned this on server and this running

http://localhost:8080/ticket-monster/index.jsf

How set default running to

http://localhost:8080/ticket-monster/index.html

please help

Comment: Where does `index.jsf` come from ? Your project have no file called `index.jsf` ? Also your web.xml already pointing to `index.html`. By default it should go to `index.html`

Comment: in web.xml is index.html but still automaticaly this project launching index.jsf

Comment: I tried build and deploying your project and by default it is all working fine. How did you deploy the application ? For me by default it is launching `http://localhost:8080/ticket-monster/` which takes me to `ticket-master` home page.

Comment: Does it help you ?